# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object' on combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a code like this

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myClientMachineAddressList As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim myClientMachineIP As String = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(0).ToString()
    Me.Text = GetComputerName()
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myClientMachineIP)
End Sub
```

Im trying to get an active Ipv4 address adapter and add it to combobox but i got this error Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'

Comment: Change `AddRange` to `Add`.

Comment: Or put curly brackets around the string to turn it into an array: `Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({myClientMachineIP})`

Comment: Changing Addrange to Add give me error

Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({myClientMachineIP}) the code is working but it only show me ipv6... i need ipv4

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your addresses by checking `AddressFamiliy`,
to filter all IPv4 addresses, `AddressFamiliy` should be equal to`AddressFamily.InterNetwork`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myClientMachineAddressList As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim myClientMachineIP = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList.Where(Function(a) a.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray()
    Me.Text = GetComputerName()
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myClientMachineIP)

End Sub
```